# How to markup District/Ward using schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

In Schema.org, we have Country, State, City, but no District or Ward.

So please help me: How to markup District/Ward using Schema.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Schema.org doesn’t have an appropriate type for your use case, use a broader type. This can go up to [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing), which can be used for *anything*.

I don’t know your definition for ward or district, but I guess [`AdministrativeArea`](http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea) might be appropriate. Otherwise its parent type [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will use AdministrativeArea as your guest!